# React push event.target.value to an array

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am new to react and now faced with a problem when trying to push the value of an input box into an array. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Generally speaking, I want to save the input value of multiple input boxes into an array. All the input boxes call the same onChange Function (because the input boxes are generated by map, they have to use the same onChange function).

Here are my codes.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
      SCAnswer:"",
      SCAnswerGroup: []
    }
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({SCAnswer: event.target.value});
    const SCAnswerGroup = this.state.SCAnswerGroup;
    SCAnswerGroup.push(this.state.SCAnswer);
    this.setState({SCAnswerGroup});
  }

  BuildAnswerGroup(){
    const n = this.state.DropdownValue;
    if (this.state.DropdownValue ==="Number of answers") {
        return(<div></div>)
    }
    else {
    return [...Array(n)].map((e, i) => 
    <div key={i} className="SingleChoiceAnswers">
       <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} size="100%" type="text" className="SingleChoiceAnswer"/>
    </div>   
    )}}

  render(){
    return(
    ...
    { this.BuildAnswerGroup()}
    )
  }
}
```

For example, if the inputs of two input boxes are "Yes", "No", the expected value of SCAnswerGroup is ["Yes", "No"]. However, what I got is ["YYeYesN"]. I think each letter change is saved to the array but the last letter. Could you please help me to get the expected results?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There are mistakes in your handlechage method but before attempting to answer please post the entire component here including the render etc...

Comment: Yes I know there are mistakes. The entire component is quite big include child components and grandchild components. I just post the part where there is a mistake (the handleChange()). I have added some, I hope now it would be enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass another argument index to the `handleChange` function and then in function, change the index in the array

```
handleChange(event, i){
  this.setState({SCAnswer: event.target.value});
  const SCAnswerGroup = this.state.SCAnswerGroup;
  SCAnswerGroup[i] = event.target.value;
  this.setState({SCAnswerGroup});
}
// in the render method
<input onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event, i)} />
```